# How to use the output of a command in another

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write a batch script to extract both audio and video from some mp4's in a same folder using `ffmpeg`, then remerging them in an mkv, but trying to conserve the audio language.

I got a script working perfectly to do it without considering the language:

```bash
chcp 65001
for %%a in (*.mp4) do (
    "ffmpeg" -i %%a -c:v copy -bsf hevc_mp4toannexb "%%~na.h265" -c:a copy "%%~na.aac"
    del %%a
    "mkvmerge" -o "%%~na.mkv" "%%~na.h265" "%%~na.aac"
)
```

That one works smoothly.

I've got another script which outputs the audio language to feed the mkvmerge code and I got this:

```bash
chcp 65001
for %%a in (*.mp4) do (
    "mediainfo" --Output=Audio;%%Language/String2%%  "%%a"
)
```

I get the code (`en`, `ja`, `es`, etc.).

The problem is that I don't know how to set the output of the second script to use it in the first one.

I should store the output from the second one and the `mkvmerge` command would be something like that:

```bash
"mkvmerge" -o "%%~na.mkv" "%%~na.h265" --language TID:(output from the other script) "%%~na.aac"
```

That way every new mkv keeps the original audio language from the mp4.

I've been searching today for it but I couldn't find the answer to my need.

PS: Don't ask why I need that that way instead of just remuxing directly the mp4 to an mkv, I just need it to be that way.

As an aside, `ffmpeg`, `mediainfo` and `mkvmerge` are double quoted because they are not env variables in my laptop, so I just set the paths to the exe's and there are spaces in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FOR /F command is used to capture the output of a command. This is untested.

```
chcp 65001
for %%a in (*.mp4) do (
    FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('^""C:\MediaInfo\MediaInfo.exe" "--Output=Audio;[%%Language/String2%%]" "%%a"^"') DO (
        "mkvmerge" -o "%%~na.mkv" "%%~na.h265" --language TID:%%G "%%~na.aac"
    )
)
```

Comment: I've tried:

`chcp 65001
for %%a in (*.mp4) do (

"ffmpeg" -i %%a -c:v copy -bsf hevc_mp4toannexb "%%~na.h265" -c:a copy "%%~na.aac"

del %%a

    FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('"MediaInfo" --Output=Audio;%%Language/String2%%  "%%a"') DO (
        "mkvmerge" -o "%%~na.mkv" "%%~na.h265" --language TID:%%G "%%~na.aac"
    )
)`
but it doesn't work properly. It only extracts both audio and video. Nothing else.

Comment: I don't have your software.  So you will have to test with the additional command I gave you and see how the %%G variable is coming out.  Just run this in a batch file and see what it outputs: `FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('"MediaInfo" --Output=Audio;%%Language/String2%%  "SomeFile.mp4"') DO echo Languages=%%G`

Comment: It doesn't work. The path to the mediainfo.exe has spaces in it and it fails, even properly doublequoted, exactly as you propose.

Comment: If you search StackOverFlow, you will see plenty of batch files that successfully use MediaInfo inside a `FOR /F` command.

Comment: I downloaded and installed your software. Then finally found an mp4 online that had multiple languages.  I reread your question and comments and I think I finally understood what your issue was with using MediaInfo. See updated code.

Comment: Thanks, mate, for taking the time to try it yourself. It worked perfectly. I completed the command with the ffmpeg part and it was great. Thank you, really appreciate it. Just in case, I'm using the MediaInfo CLI version (if someone ever needs to do this).